# SASS @each and @for generate nothing

Tags: for-loop, sass, each

This code does not generate error but classes was not created.

Do someone have an idea ?

```
$properties: margin, padding, height, margin-top, margin-bottom, border, 
height;

@each $property in $properties {
  @for $size from 1 through 500 {
    .#{$property}-#{$size} {
      $property: #{$size}px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You also need to interpolate the css-property: `#{$property}: #{$size}px;`